# Sharing between public key Client and server using Scoket

Tags: java, security, cryptography, public-key-encryption, private-key

How can I share between public key Client and server using Scoket.

Server Side

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.security.KeyFactory;
    import java.security.KeyPair;
    import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.PrivateKey;
    import java.security.PublicKey;
    import java.security.spec.EncodedKeySpec;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
    import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
    import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.UUID;

    import com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64;

    import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
    import java.security.KeyPair;
    import java.security.PrivateKey;
    import java.security.PublicKey;
    import java.security.KeyFactory;
    import java.security.spec.EncodedKeySpec;
    import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
    import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.UUID; 
    public class Server {

           private static final String String = null;
        public static void main(String[] arg) {

               String pub = generateKeys("DSA", 1024);



          try {



             ServerSocket socketConnection = new ServerSocket(11111);

             System.out.println("Server Waiting");

             Socket pipe = socketConnection.accept();

             ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = new    
                ObjectInputStream(pipe.getInputStream());

             ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = new 
                ObjectOutputStream(pipe.getOutputStream());

             // Server Read Operations   


             String Pub1 = (String) serverInputStream.readObject();



          // Server Write Operations   

             serverOutputStream.writeObject(ran1);
             serverOutputStream.writeObject(pub);


             serverInputStream.close();
             serverOutputStream.close();


          }  catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e); 
          }
       }
           public static String generateKeys(String keyAlgorithm, int numBits) {

                  try {
                       // Get the public/private key pair
                       KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(keyAlgorithm);
                       keyGen.initialize(numBits);
                       KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
                       PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
                       PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

                        System.out.println("\n" + "Generating key/value pair using " + privateKey.getAlgorithm() + " algorithm");

                       // Get the bytes of the public and private keys
                       byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKey.getEncoded();
                       byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();

                       // Get the formats of the encoded bytes
                       String formatPrivate = privateKey.getFormat(); // PKCS#8
                       String formatPublic = publicKey.getFormat(); // X.509

                       String pv=String.valueOf(privateKeyBytes);

                       System.out.println("Private Key : " + Base64.encode(pv));

                       String pb=String.valueOf(publicKeyBytes);
                       System.out.println("Public Key : " + Base64.encode(pb));
                     //  return pb;

                      // System.out.println("Private Key : " + Base64.encode(String.valueOf(privateKeyBytes)));
                      // System.out.println("Public Key : " + Base64.encode(String.valueOf(publicKeyBytes)));

                       // The bytes can be converted back to public and private key objects
                       KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(keyAlgorithm);
                       EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
                       PrivateKey privateKey2 = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

                       EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
                       PublicKey publicKey2 = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

                       // The original and new keys are the same
                      // System.out.println("  Are both private keys equal? " + privateKey.equals(privateKey2));
                      // System.out.println("  Are both public keys equal? " + publicKey.equals(publicKey2));
                  } catch (InvalidKeySpecException specException) {
                       System.out.println("Exception");
                       System.out.println("Invalid Key Spec Exception");
                  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                       System.out.println("Exception");
                       System.out.println("No such algorithm: " + keyAlgorithm);
                  }
                return null;
             }

    }
```

Client Side

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.spec.EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException; 
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64;

public class Client {

   public static void main(String[] arg) {
      try {




            String Pub1 = generateKeys("DSA", 1024);

         Socket socketConnection = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 11111);
         ObjectOutputStream clientOutputStream = new
            ObjectOutputStream(socketConnection.getOutputStream());
         ObjectInputStream clientInputStream = new 
            ObjectInputStream(socketConnection.getInputStream());

   // Client Write Operations      


         clientOutputStream.writeObject(Pub1);


//   Client Read Operations 


         String Pub = (String)clientInputStream.readObject();

       System.out.println("The Public Key  = " + Pub);

       System.out.println("The Public Key 1  = " + Pub1);



         clientOutputStream.close();
         clientInputStream.close();

      } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e); }
   }

   public static void log(Object aObject)
   {
     System.out.println( String.valueOf(aObject) );

  }
   private static String generateKeys(String keyAlgorithm, int numBits) {

       try {
            // Get the public/private key pair
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(keyAlgorithm);
            keyGen.initialize(numBits);
            KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
            PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

             System.out.println("\n" + "Generating key/value pair using " + privateKey.getAlgorithm() + " algorithm");

            // Get the bytes of the public and private keys
            byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKey.getEncoded();
            byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();

            // Get the formats of the encoded bytes
            String formatPrivate = privateKey.getFormat(); // PKCS#8
            String formatPublic = publicKey.getFormat(); // X.509

            String s=String.valueOf(privateKeyBytes);

            System.out.println("Private Key : " + Base64.encode(s));

            String pb=String.valueOf(publicKeyBytes);
            System.out.println("Public Key : " + Base64.encode(pb));

           // System.out.println("Private Key : " + Base64.encode(String.valueOf(privateKeyBytes)));
           // System.out.println("Public Key : " + Base64.encode(String.valueOf(publicKeyBytes)));

            // The bytes can be converted back to public and private key objects
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(keyAlgorithm);
            EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
            PrivateKey privateKey2 = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

            EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
            PublicKey publicKey2 = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

            // The original and new keys are the same
           // System.out.println("  Are both private keys equal? " + privateKey.equals(privateKey2));
           // System.out.println("  Are both public keys equal? " + publicKey.equals(publicKey2));
       } catch (InvalidKeySpecException specException) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
            System.out.println("Invalid Key Spec Exception");
       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
            System.out.println("No such algorithm: " + keyAlgorithm);
       }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to share public key to each other mean that want to send public key of server to client and client public key to server and also want to save public/private key.

Comment: Next time, you should edit your initial post and include your question there. There is a tiny "edit" button below each post. This time, I've helped you out.